# How to copy a certain amout of lines to a new txt file in bash using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a txt file which contains chapters, I want to copy each chapter to a new txt file using bash.
for example:

"CHAPTER I. Down the Rabbit-Hole
Alice was beginning to get very .......

CHAPTER II. The Pool of Tears

‘Curiouser and curiouser!’ cried Alice (she was so much surprised, that
for the moment she quite forgot how to speak good English); .....
"

I want to create 2 files 1 for each chapter.

```
awk 'BEGIN{start="0"; end="0"; chapters="0"}
{if($1 -eq chapter){
    chapter++
    sed -n "$start,$end" Alice_book_aux > Alice_book_chapter_$chapter
    start = end
}
end++;}' Alice_book
```

This is what I thought I should do but is won't work :(

Comment: How are the chapters divided? How about the paragraphs? Please post short sample of the data. along with the expected output. Don't post them as images or comments. Thanks.

Comment: Does `/^CHAPTER/` recognize the start of each chapter?

Comment: `$1 -eq chapter` I think you're getting awk and shell confused. You're also using `chapters` in one spot and `chapter` in others...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll make assumptions based on the given example.

1. `AWK` has an input parser that can process input through regexp filters
2. `SED` is an adequate tools to take excerpts from input, but `AWK` will suffice here.

Thus your revised code :

```
awk 'BEGIN {chapter=0;chapfile="";}
     /^"?CHAPTER / {
                       chapter++;
                       chapfile="Alice_book_chapter_"chapter;
                       printf "" > chapfile;
                   }
     { if (chapter -gt 0) {
        print >> chapfile;
       }
     }' Alice_book
```

As suggested by @karakfa, the awk script can be reduced to this :

```
awk '/^"?CHAPTER / {
                       chapter++;
                       chapfile="Alice_book_chapter_"chapter;
                   }
     chapter{
        print > chapfile;
     }
' Alice_book
```

Comment: `BEGIN` block is not necessary.  `-gt` should be `>`.  `printf ""` line is not required.  `print >>` can be `print >`. Actually, last block can be replaced with `chapter{print > chapfile}`

Comment: @karakfa I agree. However, i guess it's more appropriate to keep the verbose form for OP understanding. I'll add your suggested compact form to the answer.

Comment: Better but still `BEGIN` block is not necessary, there is no reason to initialize variables to their default values. It can be removed without any effect.

Comment: @karakfa done. I'm an old one, which always initializes and never relies on the defaults ^^